# how to load textures and use it on obj modele

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

In babylon js when you load an obj modele how could you edit it and add textures on colors?

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("skull/", "skull.obj", scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either when scene append was successful, inside inner scope:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("skull/", "skull.obj", scene, function (scene) {
  scene.meshes[1].material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture('url/image.jpg', scene)
});
```

Or outside by async/await:

```
var loadedScene = await BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("skull/", "skull.obj", scene);
loadedScene .meshes[1].material.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture('url/image.jpg', scene)
```